# Css force new line in between text in content

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
header h1:after {
    content:"Alumni Association";
}
```

and I want it to display as follows:

Alumni

Association

I have tried `\a, \n, <br>` etc but none of them work.

I am looking for a purely CSS solution as that is all I have access to...

Comment: This is just a matter of finding the right way to include a line-break into css content. Thus marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: pre;` to your class.

```
h1:after {
    content: 'Hello\AWorld';
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `white-space:pre;` to the styling, and then include `\A` in the text:

```
header h1:after {
    white-space:pre;
    content:"Alumni \a Association";
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fqo4aLd/)

Answer (score 1):

Try: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r59Lktob/1/)**

```
header h1:after {
    content:"Alumni \A Association"; 
  white-space: pre; /* or pre-wrap */    

}
```

For reference: **[Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content)**

> The 'display' property controls whether the content is placed in a
>   block or inline box.
>
> The following rule causes the string "Chapter: " to be generated
>   before each H1 element:
>
> H1:before {    content: "Chapter: ";   display: inline; }
>
> Authors may include newlines in the generated content by writing the
>   "\A" escape sequence in one of the strings after the 'content'
>   property. This inserted line break is still subject to the
>   'white-space' property. See "Strings" and "Characters and case" for
>   more information on the "\A" escape sequence.
>
> h1:before {
>       display: block;
>       text-align: center;
>       white-space: pre;
>       content: "chapter\A hoofdstuk\A chapitre" }
>
> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).

Answer (score 1):

```
header h1:after {
    content:"Alumni \A Association";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header h1:after {
    content:"Alumni \A Association";
    white-space: pre;
}
```